# jQuery Select2 - Select ajax-submitted value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a form that submits a new entry via ajax and returns the entry data. I'm trying to get the returned data to be automatically selected in the Select2 field. I can get the id entered as the input value, but I'm not sure how to get the text to be displayed in the span.

Here's the JS I have so far:

```
function clientFormatResult(client){
    var markup = client.first_name + ' ' + client.last_name + ' (' + client.username + ')';
    return markup; 
}

function clientFormatSelection(client) {
    $('#client-input').empty();
    $('#client-input').append('<input type="hidden" name="client" value="' + client.id + '" />');
    return client.first_name + ' ' + client.last_name + ' (' + client.username + ')';
}

$('#client-selection').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a client',
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'clients/get_client_list',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term) {
            return {filter: term};
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
    formatResult: clientFormatResult,
    formatSelection: clientFormatSelection,
    dropdownCssClass: 'bigdrop',
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        var id = element.val();
        if(id != '') {
            $.ajax('clients/get_client_list/'+id).done(function(data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    }
});

$('#add-client-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this),
        url = form.attr('action'),
        data = form.serialize();
    $.post(url, data, function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('.form-response').fadeOut(400);
        if(status == 'success') {
            $('#add-client-modal').modal('hide');
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#client-selection').select2('val', data.client_id);
        } else {
            $('#add-client-failure').fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, the text displayed is meant to be like "John Smith (smithj)".

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out, it was an issue with the data I was returning. Select2 was expecting an `id` variable, but I was returning it as `client_id`.